# translated from <language> by <translator> in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, languages

I could not find a biblatex style showing the language of a reference from which it is translated when the `translator` field is used even though the fields `language` and 
`orilanguage` are correctly filled in. In the `biblatex` guide (v1.7), I can see p. 183 that strings such as `fromenglish` are allowed but I cannot figure out how to have them in the final output.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know how your `.bib` file looks like. But try using it like this:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[
    style=authortitle,
    backend=biber,
]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book {foo,
    author = {Foo, Francis},
    title = {All about Foo},
    year = {2011},
    location = {Footown},
    translator = {Translator, Hans},
    origlanguage = {german},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\textheight=50pt

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Maybe there's a spelling mistake in your file as you wrote `orilanguage` instead of `origlanguage`.

The `fromenglish` etc. strings you mentioned are just used in the `.lbx` files for localization. In my example it just prints "from the German" as it is used in the bibliography.

[image]

Comment: you were correct. The `orilanguage` was the problem. Thanks. Sorry for the noise.